# Python - sort a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

i have the following list of dictionaries:

```
my_list = [ 
    {
       "field1": value,
       "field2": value,
       "time": 2017-12-01 14:34:12,
       "field3": value
    },
    {
       "field1": value,
       "field2": value,
       "time": 2017-12-01 14:31:20,
       "field3": value
    },
    {
       "field1": value,
       "field2": value,
       "time": 2017-12-01 14:40:02,
       "field3": value
    }
]
```

How can i sort this list by the `time` value of the dictionaries?
(so the dictionary with the highest `time` value will be in the first index of the list and so on..)

Thanks!

Comment: `sorted(my_list, key = lambda d: d['time'], reverse = True)`

Comment: Is there any chance this doesn't work for timestamp values?